# Objective - C / iterating though NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, iteration

---- Alert: Noob question incoming ----

Basically I have a bunch of text fields in _textFields, and I want to make it so, that when I press a button (next), the current textfield resigns first responder, and the next textfield in the array gets the first responder.

Now I don't know how to access the counter + 1 element.

```
for (UITextField *counter in _textFields)
    if ([counter isFirstResponder])
         [*insert text here* becomeFirstResponder];
```

Edit:
Now I've come up with this way, but I have a feeling there's a more elegant way of doing it.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [_textFields count] - 1 ; ++i )
    if ( [[_textFields objectAtIndex: i] isFirstResponder]) {
        [[_textFields objectAtIndex: i+1 ] becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have that feeling? What you should worry about is what happens when the last text field in the array is the current first responder...

Comment: Yes, I've resolved that by placing an if statement above the for, which only lets the for start if the last != first responder.

As for my feeling, I thought for ( ; ; ) is kind of an old thing, I usually only see for ( in ) cycles in the newer codes.

Comment: Old, yes, but that doesn't mean bad, just different.